# Why do I get different results visually if I include this CSS code as a different file

Tags: css

I am trying the code in the link shown below for responsive layout design.

1) As it it, if the CSS code is included in the html code displays perfectly as expected

2) But if I move the exact CSS code as a different file and link to it from the html code, visually the boxes layout don't work so well. The result seems similar in different browsers.

Would someone know the reason for that? I was expecting to get more similar visual results

Also would it be good in general for a website html code to include the css in the html code as in (1) or as a different file as in (2)

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_website_layout_blog

Here is the code I used to link to css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<body>
<head>
  <title>My page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

here is the top code of the CSS sheet

```
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the result

[image]

---

edit

reviewed css sheet code after Lunex answer (top part)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css file. Let's say you name it "style.css".

In this file you put all the content which is in the < style > tag.

In your html file inside the head tag you add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

This should be working, considering you've done everything right.

**Edit for your edit:**

You don't need html tags in your css file.

The content of the html file should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- the body content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

The content of your css file should be:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

// ...

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lunex, it seems to have worked. I removed all the html tags and kept only the CSS code, and I obtain visually the same result as the original code.